# Can one develop an application with Bluetooth support on iOS using Flash Builder 4.5?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flex, flash-cs5, bluetooth

I have heard about Flash Builder 4.5.1. As I have understood, one can make an application using Flex with Flash Builder 4.5.1 and also export the release build for iOS, Android and Blackberry.

Is it possible to include Bluetooth functionality in an application this way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently for iOS specifically, there is [no Bluetooth API exposed via the SDK](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/8900-there-api-bluetooth.html). While the rest of this answer may apply to other platforms, you aren't going to be able to make it work in the iPhone.

For other platforms... as far as I know there's is no API for Bluetooth access in Flex. You have a few other options though:

- [This document](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Creating_Adobe_AIR_game_controlled_with_a_Wii_remo-10884.html) describes how to use a third party tool or library to interact with Bluetooth (specifically to interact with a Wii remote, but you could presumably extend that to more general purpose applications).
- AIR supports [native extensions](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/extensions/index.html), which you may be able to use to access the native Bluetooth functionality on each device.

Both options may require you to handle the cross-platform nature of the problem yourself, however (unless you use a third-party Bluetooth API that is itself cross platform).

You may also want to check out [this blog post](http://biorex21.wordpress.com/2011/04/08/bluetoothsender-or-yet-another-native-process-post/), which goes in to some detail about how a user achieved a similar thing to what you may be asking for.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience I don't think there is a way through flash builder.

Answer (score 0):

Not with Flash Builder, I strongly recommend learning Objective C it gives you many features and advantages such as the gamekit multiplayer tools, I recommend a visit to the apple iOS developer site (http://developer.apple.com/technologies/ios/).
Here is a quick tutorial of [Objective-C](http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_objectivec/).